# Error Defining Foreign Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys, data-integrity

I have the following two database tables defined:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Classrooms] (
  [ID]               INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
  [SystemAccount_ID] INT          NOT NULL,
  [ClassroomName]    VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID]),
  CONSTRAINT [FK_Classrooms_SystemAccount] FOREIGN KEY ([SystemAccount_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[SystemAccounts] ([ID])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Students] (
   [ID]               INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
   [SystemAccount_ID] INT          NOT NULL,
   [Classroom_ID]     INT          NULL,
   [PhotoID]          INT          NULL,
   [FirstName]        VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
   [LastName]         VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
   [NewsTemplate]     TINYINT      NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [PK_Students] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
   CONSTRAINT [FK_Students_Classrooms] FOREIGN KEY ([Classroom_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Classrooms] ([ID]),
   CONSTRAINT [FK_Students_SystemAccounts] FOREIGN KEY ([SystemAccount_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[SystemAccounts] ([ID])
);
```

Data model details:

- Students belong to zero or one classroom via `Classroom_ID` FK
- Students belong to one System Account via `SystemAccount_ID` FK
- Classrooms belong to one System Account via `SystemAccount_ID` FK (implying a system account can have zero or more Classrooms)

What I'm attempting to do is enforce when students are added to a classroom (by setting the Classroom_ID key in the Students table) that the classroom belongs to the same system account as the student. I could easily enforce this at the business logic layer but then I'd be requiring every programmer to remember to do this. So ideally, I'd be able to do this at the data layer as a constraint.

I tried adding a FK constraint to the Students table:

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_Students_ToTable] FOREIGN KEY ([SystemAccount_ID]) REFERENCES [Classrooms]([SystemAccount_ID])
```

Which results in the following error compliments of SQL Server:

> Update cannot proceed due to validation errors.
>   Please correct the following errors and try again.
>
> SQL71516 :: The referenced table '[dbo].[Classrooms]' contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it should be persisted.

I've tried a few different things but my SQL mojo isn't powerful enough to hack past this one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add an unique key on Classrooms.SystemAccount_ID `ALTER TABLE Classrooms
ADD CONSTRAINT constraintName UNIQUE (SystemAccount_ID)`

Comment: You're trying to create a FK that references the `SystemAccount_ID` column in `CLassrooms`, but that's **neither** the primary key for that table, nor is there a unique constraint on that column. One of these two conditions **must be given** for that column to be referenced by a foreign key constraint! Or did you want to reference the `Classrooms.ID` column instead?

Comment: @Mihai One detail I neglected to mention is that system accounts can have zero or more classrooms. I'm assuming the unique constraint that you suggested will prevent me from having more than one classroom assigned to the same system account.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for your help. I think the unique constraint is a tuple of Classrooms.ID, Classrooms.SystemAccount_ID since a SystemAccount can have zero or more Classrooms. If I slap a unique constraint on the SystemAccount_ID column in Classrooms then I'm assuming I won't be able to have more than one classroom per system account. Is that correct?

Comment: @OGHaza Thanks for the help. The problem I have with adding this logic to a stored procedure is I'm stuck with the same problem as if I added this logic to the business layer. All developers maintaining this system will need to know about this secret detail. I really want to add this to a Check Constraint or FK Constraint if it is feasible.

Comment: I think you need to further normalize your model. Remove the system account from rooms and student in to another set of tables -> room ownership, student mentor for example and then use these tables as the  primary key source for a room allocation table

Comment: @Gavin That's an interesting idea that I'll certainly consider. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add a `UNIQUE` constraint on the combination of the two columns in `Classrooms`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Classrooms] (
  [ID]               INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
  [SystemAccount_ID] INT          NOT NULL,
  [ClassroomName]    VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Table] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID]),
  CONSTRAINT [FK_Classrooms_SystemAccount] 
    FOREIGN KEY ([SystemAccount_ID]) 
    REFERENCES [dbo].[SystemAccounts] ([ID]),
  CONSTRAINT [UQ_Classrooms_ID_SystemAccount_ID] 
    UNIQUE ([SystemAccount_ID], [ID])
);
```

Then, in the `Students` table, combine the two `FOREIGN KEY` constraints into one, or in your case (because `Classroom_ID` isnullable), change the FK to `Classroom` to use the combination of the two columns:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Students] (
  [ID]               INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
  [SystemAccount_ID] INT          NOT NULL,
  [Classroom_ID]     INT          NULL,
  [PhotoID]          INT          NULL,
  [FirstName]        VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
  [LastName]         VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL,
  [NewsTemplate]     TINYINT      NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Students] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
  CONSTRAINT [FK_Students_Classrooms] 
    FOREIGN KEY ([SystemAccount_ID], [Classroom_ID]) 
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Classrooms] ([SystemAccount_ID], [ID]),
  CONSTRAINT [FK_Students_SystemAccounts]         -- this wouldn't be needed if
    FOREIGN KEY ([SystemAccount_ID])              -- Classrooms_ID was NOT NULL
    REFERENCES [dbo].[SystemAccounts] ([ID])
);
```

Comment: I'll give this a try and accept as the answer once I get a chance to come back to it. Thanks for taking the time to help me out. I appreciate it.